# Figuring out why character matching doesn't work

Tags: r, merge, tidyverse

For the project at hand, I am forced to join several data frames by a character column. This is sometimes problematic due to - for example - trailing whitespace but can also be remedied easily. However, in this case the joining does not work and I am unable to figure out what distinguishes the character values in the column used to do the joining.

Since in its original format the problem was not reproducible, here is a [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ALOpjMY1s1buk0Y&id=A78D7A6556BD4759%2182751&cid=A78D7A6556BD4759) where data in question can be downloaded. It looks like this:

```
readRDS("path/sourceA") -> sourceA
sourceA
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Name                  category
  <chr>                    <dbl>
1 Grundschule Kronsberg        1

readRDS("path/sourceB") -> sourceB
sourceB
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Name                  value
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Grundschule Kronsberg     2
```

I want to join these data frames together using the common id variable `Name`. As you can see, it appears the value is exactly the same in both frames. However, when I apply *any* joining procedure, this happens:

```
library(tidyverse)
joined.df <- full_join(sourceA, sourceB, by = "Name")

joined.df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name                  category value
  <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Grundschule Kronsberg        1    NA
2 Grundschule Kronsberg       NA     2
```

In trying to figure this out, I tried to remove the whitespace from the `Name` column but, using standard procedure, was only able to so for `sourceA`. For `sourceB` it looks as if the procedure does not cut out the whitespace in between "Grundschule" and "Kronsberg".

```
joined.df %>%
  mutate(Name_test = stringr::str_replace_all(Name, fixed(" "), ""))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Name                  category value Name_test            
  <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                
1 Grundschule Kronsberg        1    NA GrundschuleKronsberg 
2 Grundschule Kronsberg       NA     2 Grundschule Kronsberg
```

Weirdly, when using `stringr::str_replace_all(Name, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", "")`, it works:

```
joined.df %>%
  mutate(Name_test = stringr::str_replace_all(Name, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", ""))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Name                  category value Name_test           
  <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               
1 Grundschule Kronsberg        1    NA GrundschuleKronsberg
2 Grundschule Kronsberg       NA     2 GrundschuleKronsberg
```

I don't know anything about how the lookup in `"\\p{WHITE_SPACE}"`differs from `fixed(" ")` under the hood, but I thought it might be good clue for someone who does.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get just one row.

Comment: Same here, solution with `full_join()` seems fine.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Did some updates last week, checking that now

Comment: `merge(sourceA,sourceB, by = "Name")` works as well, you could try that if there are package/update troubles.

Comment: I did try that. The problem is not contingent on using `dplyr`s joining verbs

Comment: Haven't found any pointers yet. The weird thing is that if I copy the code from this question into a clean work environment, I cannot reproduce the error either. When I run the entirety of the code (including `dput()`), I end up with what I described.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? 
Maybe one of the " " just looks like a space but is some other character? Maybe something similar to the " vs ” problem?

Comment: This my hunch also. The question is why does `stri_replace_all_charclass()` detect the whitespace while `str_replace_all()` does not. The source of the data file is an .xlsx file

Comment: Still don't know the root cause of the issue, but found a solution described above

Comment: I think its not about the functions itself but about the search-pattern. Once it is " " and once it is "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}". WHITE_SPACE is described here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.4.3/topics/stringi-search-charclass. So i think one of your " " is a common " " and the other one (which cant be replaced by " " but by WHITE_SPACE) is some sort of white_space not identical to " ". I'd try to get the ascii or unicode values for the " " and see if they are identical.

Comment: You are right, as `sourceB %>%   mutate(Name_test = stringr::str_replace_all(Name, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", ""))` works as well.

Comment: So, using the `asc()` function from `gtools`, I was able to determine the difference between the two strings! For `sourceA`, it is a regular white space, while for `sourceB`, there is a) an extra ASCII code compared to `sourceA` (ASCII decimal 32 replaced with 160) and b) somehow a code denoting the letter Â (ASCII decimal 194) snuck in there. Why these two decimals displayed as a regular white space I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a discussion in the comments, I was able to solve the problem. While the `Name` variables looked identical (and where parsed identically by `dput()`), there was a subtle difference when converting the characters into their ASCII codes:

```
library(gtools)

asc(sourceA$Name)
      Grundschule Kronsberg
 [1,]                    71
 [2,]                   114
 [3,]                   117
 [4,]                   110
 [5,]                   100
 [6,]                   115
 [7,]                    99
 [8,]                   104
 [9,]                   117
[10,]                   108
[11,]                   101
[12,]                    32
[13,]                    75
[14,]                   114
[15,]                   111
[16,]                   110
[17,]                   115
[18,]                    98
[19,]                   101
[20,]                   114
[21,]                   103

asc(sourceB$Name)
      Grundschule Kronsberg
 [1,]                    71
 [2,]                   114
 [3,]                   117
 [4,]                   110
 [5,]                   100
 [6,]                   115
 [7,]                    99
 [8,]                   104
 [9,]                   117
[10,]                   108
[11,]                   101
[12,]                   194
[13,]                   160
[14,]                    75
[15,]                   114
[16,]                   111
[17,]                   110
[18,]                   115
[19,]                    98
[20,]                   101
[21,]                   114
[22,]                   103
```

`sourceB` has an extra code compared to `sourceA` and different values in position 12 and 13. Using `chr()` (also from `gtools`), I was able to re-convert the ASCII codes into characters:

```
    chr(asc(sourceA$Name))
 [1] "G" "r" "u" "n" "d" "s" "c" "h" "u" "l" "e" " " "K" "r" "o" "n" "s" "b" "e" "r" "g"

chr(asc(sourceB$Name))
 [1] "G" "r" "u" "n" "d" "s" "c" "h" "u" "l" "e" "Â" " " "K" "r" "o" "n" "s" "b" "e" "r" "g"
```

In `sourceB`, there is an extra Â (ASCII decimal code 194) in the string, and the white space is coded with the decimal 160 instead of 32. I still don't know why in conjunction these two ASCII codes were displayed as a regular white space, but was able to solve the issue by simply replacing all white spaces with `" "`

```
sourceB <- sourceB %>%
  mutate(Name = stringr::str_replace_all(Name, "\\p{WHITE_SPACE}", " "))

full_join(sourceA, sourceB, by = "Name")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Name                  category value
  <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Grundschule Kronsberg        1     2
```

This (somehow) changed the ASCII codes so that they now align with one another:

```
chr(asc(sourceB$Name))
 [1] "G" "r" "u" "n" "d" "s" "c" "h" "u" "l" "e" " " "K" "r" "o" "n" "s" "b" "e" "r" "g"
```